# What is the difference between @Named , @Qualifier and @Component

Tags: java, spring

I know @Name is Java standard (JSR 330) whereas @Qualifier and @Component are Spring Specific. But my question is @Name is equivalent to @Qualifier or it is equivalent to @Component? In my code,  I used @Named in place of both(@Qualifier and @Component) and it is working perfectly fine. So I got confused.

While surfing on internet to investigate this more somewhere it is mentioned like @Name is equivalent to @Qualifier and somewhere it's mentioned it is equivalent to @Component. Also in Java Doc it is not mentioned clearly.

Please guide..!

Comment: show the code and what is your spring version?